# How to change slider's value by changing the input value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-ui-slider

i'm trying to change the value of a slider when the user changes the value ot the input field.

```
<div class="option-block">
    <label for="radius-top-left">Radius T-Left</label>
    <input id="radius-top-left" type="text" value="0" max="100" min="0">
    <div class="multi">
        <span id="slider-radius-top-left"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my HTML code. And the code below is what i made to change the input value by changing the position of the slider.

```
$("#slider-radius-top-left").slider({
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#radius-top-left").val(ui.value);
        first_border_radius();          
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        $("#radius-top-left").val(ui.value); 
        first_border_radius();         
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the slider methods like this:

```
$( "#radius-top-left" ).change(function() { 
    $("#slider-radius-top-left").slider("value", $(this).val()); //option 1
    //$("#slider-radius-top-left").slider( "option", "value", $(this).val()); //option 2 - the same
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `div` instead of `span`.

```
<div class="option-block">
    <label for="radius-top-left">Radius T-Left</label>
    <input id="radius-top-left" type="text" value="0" max="100" min="0">
    <div class="multi">
        <div id="slider-radius-top-left"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can adjust the width of the slider by setting the width of the `div` element. Otherwise I was able to run your code smoothly.

Also, just in case it makes a difference, you should wrap the activation of the slider to begin on document ready.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-radius-top-left" ).slider({
        ...
    });
});
</script>
```